# R - join tables in R using logical conditions and using >, < and = operator

Tags: r, left-join, multiple-conditions

Kinda new in R, but trying to figure it out.

So, I have a query from MySQL that joins two tables based on their tunetime (Login) and combined with the TV scheadule I can check what they are watching.

In SQL I can do it like this:

```
SELECT 
    s.Device,
    s.CallLetter AS Channel,
    e.Title AS Program_Title,
    e.TitleId AS Program_Title_ID,
    s.TuneDuration AS Stream_Time,
    s.TuneTime AS Login_Time,
    e.StartDate AS StartTime,
    e.EndDate AS End_Time
FROM
    sessoeslive_canais s
        JOIN
    epg e ON s.TuneTime >= e.StartDate
        AND s.TuneTime <= e.EndDate
        AND s.CallLetter = e.CallLetter
```

But now, in R, that problem seems to be bigger.

I've written something like:

```
join <- 
 sessoeslive_canais %>%
 left_join(epg, by = c("CallLetter" == "CallLetter", "TuneTime" > "StarDate", "TuneTime" < "EndDate" ))
```

Do you have any tip on how to do in R what I've expressed in SQL?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we can use `fuzzyjoin`

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
fuzzy_left_join(sessoeslive_canais, epg, by = c("CallLetter" == "CallLetter",
      "TuneTime" = "StarDate", "TuneTime" = "EndDate" ), 
           match_fun = list(`==`, `>`, `<`)) %>%
  select(Program_Title = Title.y, Program_Title_ID = TitleId.y,
     Stream_Time = TuneDuration.x, Login_Time = TuneTime.x,
     StartTime = StartDate.y, End_Time = EndDate.y)
```

---

Or with non-equi join from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(sessoeslive_canais)[epg, on = .(CallLetter, 
         TuneTime > StartDate, TuneTime < EndDate)]
```

Comment: And the match fun is basically a glossary for the previous equal conditions right? I was reading the documentation of fuzzy but didn't led me anywhere

Comment: @Alezzpt the documention didn't include any examples

Comment: using the fuzzy_left_join it gives me an error saying "Error: All columns in a tibble must be vectors. x Column `col` is NULL"
I tried using the setDT, it works at some level, but my data.frame sample goes from 30k lines to 600k. Anyway you know how to go arround this?

Comment: @Alezzpt Please show a small reproducible example with dput so that we can test it